# How to serve client-js from push-it using node.js

Tags: node.js

I have just started using node.js. My mayor problem is lack of documentation but I'm getting through and I really like it

Now I'm trying to use [push-it](https://github.com/aaronblohowiak/Push-It) which sits on top of socket.io. The Docs mention to serve the static client-js file, but I don't know how to do that. I already tried different paths. Socket.io works out of the box, but I can't find how to do it for push-it.

I installed push-it using npm

Thanks for any tips,
Miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) or [express](http://expressjs.com/) to server static files,

exactly as the dnode docs suggest.

__dirname is the directory you're running from, it's common to use __dirname + '/public' and place your files in there

```
var connect = require('connect');
var server = connect.createServer();
server.use(connect.staticProvider(__dirname));

var dnode = require('dnode');
dnode(function (client) {
    this.cat = function (cb) {
        cb('meow');
    };
}).listen(server);
```

Comment: Hi generalhenry,
My problem is that I don't want to put the client-script in my scripts folder (that one is already set up and working) but access directly the file installed by npm. This way I ensure to always use the right version of the file.

By the way... I'm using Express.

Comment: The client scripts are in '/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/push-it/active/package/client' you can set express to serve them from there